# handledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined (Discord Bot)

Tags: javascript, discord.js, undefined

I have been dealing with an issue with my discord bot captcha. The captcha works really well but when it comes to adding a role if they verified it slaps me with

> handledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined

This is my code:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js-12');

const client = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = 'ri-';

const Captcha = require("@haileybot/captcha-generator");

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});
let captcha = new Captcha();
console.log(captcha.value);
 

const path = require("path"),
    fs = require("fs")
 
client.on('message', async message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);

    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command === 'verification') {
 
            let captcha = new Captcha();
            message.channel.send(
                "**Enter the text shown in the image below:**",
                new Discord.MessageAttachment(captcha.JPEGStream, "captcha.jpeg")
            );
            let collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector(m => m.author.id === message.author.id);
            collector.on("collect", m => {
                if (m.content.toUpperCase() === captcha.value){ message.channel.send("Verified Successfully!");
                let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === "Verified");
                message.author.roles.add(role);
                }else{ message.channel.send("Failed Verification!");}
                collector.stop();
    });
        

    }
});
        

client.login('you don't need this.');
```

Any help is appreciated! ^^

Error:
[image]

Comment: `message.author` returns a Discord User, which do not hold roles. You want a Discord Member, to get the member use `message.member` instead

Comment: TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied roles is not a Role, Snowflake or Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes. It gave me that error when I tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two problems in your code.

1. message.author refers to an user, which does not hold roles. Use message.member instead
2. Replace r.id with r.name, id is not a string.

Have a great day :)